# how to make the call to ngCordova plugins from html

Tags: angularjs, ngcordova

I am following this official documentation of ngCordova to send an Email
eMail composer plugin with ngCordova.

the angularJs controller is :

```
    module.controller('ThisCtrl', function($cordovaEmailComposer) {

 $cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function() {
   // is available
 }, function () {
   // not available
 });

  var email = {
    to: 'max@mustermann.de',
    cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
    bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
    attachments: [
      'file://img/logo.png',
      'res://icon.png',
      'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
      'file://README.pdf'
    ],
    subject: 'Cordova Icons',
    body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
    isHtml: true
  };

 $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
   // user cancelled email
 });
});
```

How to call this from html page ?
I want to when press a button, this code be called but there is no full example in their official web page

Answer (score 0):

Yes right there is not full doc. please try nraboy blog. very nice article.

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/send-email-android-ios-ionicframework/

Comment: this is for ionic. I am planning to use cordova and ng cordova ( without ionic)

Answer (score 0):

I take that you probably have found an answer since then but I had the same problem than you so I just tried a few things and this works for me:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
     var app = angular.module('propertyDeal', ['ngCordova']);
      app.controller('ThisCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaEmailComposer) {

       $scope.email = function() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

                $cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function() {
                    alert("email available");
                }, function () {
                    alert = ("email not available");
                });

              var email = {
               to: 'max@mustermann.de',
               cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
               bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
               attachments: [
                     'file://img/logo.png',
                     'res://icon.png',
                     'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
                     'file://README.pdf'
               ],
               subject: 'Cordova Icons',
               body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
               isHtml: true
             };

            $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
                alert("email not sent");
            });

        }, false);
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="ThisCtrl">
      <button class="button" ng-click="email()">Send an email</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/ngCordova/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

not quite sure it's the right way of doing it but it works...